# Cricket Wireless - mms - Android - Samsung - S5

Tags: mobile, mms

Cricket merged with AT&T. Some time ago they also gave their existing customers to either stay CDMA or change to GSM. What does that mean exactly? I don't know, but it isn't relevant for this question.

**mms format was**: area+number@mms.mycricket.com

Post AT&T merger it became

**mms format new**: area+number@mms.aiowireless.net

**@mms.aiowireless.net** worked for months, but just **stopped working** a few days ago. Cricket support doesn't help.

Here are the settings, have always been and always worked until just recently it stopped.

**Settings**→More Networks→Mobile Networks→Access Point Names

```
Name: Internet
APN: ndo
MMSC: http://mmsc.aiowireless.net
MMS Proxy: proxy.aiowireless.net
Multimedia Message Port: 80
MCC: 310
MNC: 150
APN type: default,mms,fota,hipri,supl
APN protocol: IPv4
APN roaming protocol: IPv4
Turn APN on/off: ON
```

---

Any ideas? Anyone that uses Cricket Wireless as their carrier found a solution?

---

If you don't think this should be here, inform me where I should post this question. Google this question, it's all over the forums. No answers to be found.

If you don't use mms or sms, it comes in handy when working with text or media. It's a way you can send text or media to a mobile device using email. It's very handy especially when you have to type a lot of info, edit, links; just open an mail and send to mobile device. It's very efficient if it works. Seems Cricket is falling off the boat I've grown to be satisfied with, but now becoming dissatisfied.

Cricket Wireless - is no help. If you know what a help desk function is, then you already understand. If you don't, it's people in the industry that just need jobs, they have open tickets and want to close them. They have a sheet of protocols, answers or solutions (e.g. Did you try turning off your mobile device? Did you turn off your device and remove your battery). They aren't trained and they don't have answers. Let't move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is the original question.**

My question is indeed the answer. All the settings are in my inquiry. I made no changes to my settings. It was the network that must have put something off line and didn't publicly announce it. My settings were not changed, nor "pushed". It's back online now and mms and sms seems to be working again as it did.

Answer (score 0):

I called Cricket support yesterday and i was lucky to create a ticket number. 
After 24 hours it seems like it is working better but not fixed.

They are working on this.

cricket wireless APN settings
(look at bottom of page)
https://www.cricketwireless.com/support/apps-and-services/bring-your-own-device-byod/customer/bring-your-own-android.html

Comment: cricket wireless apn settings   https://www.cricketwireless.com/support/apps-and-services/bring-your-own-device-byod/customer/bring-your-own-android.html

Comment: Hi, I've seen this or similar websites before. My phone already had these settings when I checked them a while back. The problem is that it worked after the merger with AT&T and had been working for months until just recently. Something changed, they blocked something or planning to stop supporting this... it's just not written anywhere. Cricket sucks like that I guess.

Comment: Ah, indeed it works again and I didn't change a thing. Cricket must have put something off line and then changed put it back on again. The only reason I got Cricket service is because a few years ago no carrier wanted "free from contract" deals. Must be growing pains for Cricket with AT&T messing things up and not coming our publicly to let us know and just let us suffer. Like they care at all.